# Mismatch in library file available in boost folder

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5

I run an Qt application on my PC and it's running fine (Qt 5.9.3 + MSVC 2015).
However, when I build the same application setting up Qt 5.9.3 and MSVC 2015 on my laptop, it's throwing an error:

> LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib'

I ran through my boost folder and found that only `libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib` is available *(boost\lib\stage\lib)*, which is not the same as in the error. I'm using MSVC 2015 64 bit for build & run. Also, I don't have any .sln file in the project.

Do I need to download any additional lib file?

Comment: This appears to be claiming that the build on your PC was built using MSVC 2017, while your laptop has a clean copy of MSVC 2015. You could probably change the reference to point to the vc140 version of the boost library on your laptop to work around this - they should 'just work'.

Comment: I guess some naming issue was there. I downloaded _boost_1_67_0-msvc-14.1-64.exe_ from [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.67.0/) and installed it. Moved the required lib file and it's working fine.